# PHP Warning - PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'imagick.so'

Tags: php, upgrade, php-7.3

Has anyone come across this warning before? Any files I should check other than `php.ini` or `00-ioncube.ini`? Those look to be in good order.

```
$ php -v
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'imagick.so' (tried: /usr/lib64/php/modules/imagick.so (libMagickWand.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib64/php/modules/imagick.so.so (/usr/lib64/php/modules/imagick.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0

PHP 7.3.31 (cli) (built: Sep 21 2021 10:24:03) ( NTS )

Operating System:
Operating System: CentOS Linux 7 (Core)
     CPE OS Name: cpe:/o:centos:centos:7
          Kernel: Linux 3.10.0-1160.42.2.el7.x86_64
    Architecture: x86-64
```

I upgraded PHP from version 7.1 to 7.3 on using these steps:

```
php -v
sudo yum install epel-release
yum --enablerepo=remi-php73 install php 
php -v 
systemctl restart httpd
```

I only see one `php.ini` file loaded in `/etc/`

Comment: As error says there isnt a file called **imagick.so** which is a module, this is the location of file **/usr/lib64/php/modules/imagick.so.so** it shows file extention twice **.so.so** I think that is the reason of error.

Comment: Thank you for responding.

I can confirm that the file does exist in 

/usr/lib64/php/modules/

could it be a permissions issue?


-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1118024 Feb 25  2019 imagick.so


-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1336864 Oct 14 12:04 ioncube_loader_lin_7.3.so

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check how was the imagick extension was installed:

```
rpm -qf /usr/lib64/php/modules/imagick.so
```

It looks like it is not provided by a RPM, nor built for the proper PHP version you are running (libMagickWand.so.5 is also an old version).

For a proper configuration / installation, see the [Wizard instructions](https://rpms.remirepo.net/wizard/)

At least I recommend you enable the **remi-php73** repository permanently, to ensure all extensions are taken from it.

```
yum-config-manager --enable   remi-php73
```

Then you can install the imagick extension, or any other extension you need

```
yum install php-imagick
```

Notice, in this repository you have the choice between 2 variants of this extension, above command will pick one among:

- **php-pecl-imagick-im6** build with ImageMagick version 6 (libMagickCore-6.Q16.so.7, libMagickWand-6.Q16.so.7)
- **php-pecl-imagick-im7** build with ImageMagick version 7 (libMagickCore-7.Q16HDRI.so.10, libMagickWand-7.Q16HDRI.so.10)

APIs are slightly different.

Comment: Great suggestion. Thank you. And the Wizard is a great site. Appreciate the help.  

I ran the following: rpm -qf /usr/lib64/php/modules/imagick.so. 

it returned this: file /usr/lib64/php/modules/imagick.so is not owned by any package

After running through the command lines, my original warning cleared but received this one: PHP Warning:  Module 'imagick' already loaded in Unknown on line 0. 

a restart of apache and system reboot still shows that warning so there must still be a file trying to load that on my system.

Any suggestions on clearing that other warning?

Thanks @remi

Comment: After another scan I realized that there are two ini files in /etc/php.d/ (imagick.ini and 40-imagick.ini) attempting to load imagick.so which is why I got that second error. After removing the imagick.so file, my warnings cleared up. Thanks again for all the advice.

Comment: I hope you mean, after remove the duplicated  "imagick.ini" file ;)